Homegraph API 404 Requested entity was not found
I am using the devices:requestSync API to update the status of devices.
I am passing the agentUserId, but some users are encountering a “404 Requested entity was not found” error.
After investigation, it seems that this issue occurs for users who haven’t accessed Google Home for a long time.
I am wondering if there is a specific period after which the agentUserId is deleted.
